# not able to call .net core process from .net core web application

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a ASP .NET core web application (win service) that needs to call for another .net Core process (console application) to execute. 
I have the following code for the call:

```
 var process = new Process
 {
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "dotnet",
        Arguments = @"C:\CxSASTEngine\CxEngine\Product\netcoreapp2.1\ScanClient.dll" + " blablabla",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = false,
        RedirectStandardError = false,
        CreateNoWindow = false,
    }
};

process.Start();
```

If I place the same code in a new .Net core console application, the process runs, but in the scope of the win service it fails to run.

The ScanClient.dll code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(args.Length);
                if (args.Length > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(args[0]);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
                if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Mary\Desktop\mary.txt"))
                {
                    File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Mary\Desktop\mary.txt");
                }
                File.Create(@"C:\Users\Mary\Desktop\mary.txt");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
}
```

what can be the reason for the code not to run in the scope of the win service?
Just to be fair, if I create the ScanClient as a .netFramewrok console application that generates an .exe file, the process is being executed.

Comment: Maybe look at the exception you're silently throwing away for the reason why its failing?

Comment: Are you sure it's not running? Maybe try removing the `Console.ReadLine()`

Comment: If you're running as a windows service, they don't run in an interactive session - `Console.ReadLine();` requires interaction from the user.

Comment: Thank you! once I removed the Console operation everything worked.